# How to fix an incorrect error message for Admob in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, admob

I've been trying for ages now to fix this, and I have no idea what to do so I made an account on StackOverflow because in the past few months it's been a godsend for me. in trying to load a rewarded ad using Admob in Android Studio but when I paste the code to preload the next ad after I've closed the current one it comes up with three error messages, which shouldn't be there because the code is correct. How do I fix this? Can I just upload it to google play anyway?
Here's my code (the error lines have stars ):

```
**public RewardedAd createAndLoadRewardedAd() {**      (';' expected)
        RewardedAd rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(this,
                "ca-app-pub-9041707305654469/8828610380");
        RewardedAdLoadCallback adLoadCallback = new RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onRewardedAdLoaded() {
                Log.d("TAG", "The rewarded ad loaded");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError adError) {
                Log.d("TAG", "The rewarded ad failed to load");
            }
        };
        rewardedAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build(), adLoadCallback);
        **return rewardedAd;** (cannot return value from a method with a void reusult type)
    }



    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
  btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          if (rewardedAd.isLoaded()) {
              Activity activityContext = MainActivity.this;
              RewardedAdCallback adCallback = new RewardedAdCallback() {
                  @Override
                  public void onRewardedAdOpened() {
                      Log.d("TAG", "The rewarded ad opened");
                  }
                  @Override
                  public void onRewardedAdClosed() {
                      **this.rewardedAd = createAndLoadRewardedAd();** (cannot resolve symbol 'rewardedAd')
                      Log.d("TAG", "the reward ad closed");
                  }
                  @Override
                  public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem reward) {
                      tvscore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoretextView);
                      tvscore.setText(String.valueOf(score + fivehundred));
                      score = score + fivehundred;
                      Log.d("TAG", "user earned reward");
                  }
                  @Override
                  public void onRewardedAdFailedToShow(AdError adError) {
                      Log.d("TAG", "The rewarded ad failed to load.");
                  }
              };
              rewardedAd.show(activityContext, adCallback);
          } else {
              Log.d("TAG", "The rewarded ad wasn't loaded yet.");
          }
      }
  });
```

Comment: _it comes up with three error messages._ What are those three error messages?

Comment: on the line  'public RewardedAd createAndLoadRewardedAd() {' it says ';' expected, on the line 'return rewardedAd;' it says 'cannot return a value from a method with a void result type', and on the line 'this.rewardedAd = createAndLoadRewardedAd();' it says 'cannot resolve symbol 'rewardedad' '.